# Neo4j 3.0 community edition not run from terminal in mac osx

Tags: macos, neo4j, terminal

I have installed the .dmg file according to the  [following instructions](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/#_mac_osx_installer) but when I try to run neo4j from terminal i got an error.

```
$ neo4j start
-bash: neo4j: command not found
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you can go to the terminal to the application folder of Neo4j app. For example:

```
$ cd /Applications/Neo4j\ Community\ Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
```

And from this folder start `neo4j-shell`, but get error:

```
$ ./neo4j-shell
./neo4j-shell: line 26: ./neo4j-shared.sh: No such file or directory
```

So, I think, is an issue for OSX package.

As an alternative, you can download server (not desktop) version (tar archive) from this page http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/ and use `neo4j-shell` from this version - he is well connected with running a desktop version of neo4j.

Comment: stdob, thanks! it finally worked! @MichaelHunger any official solution for the dmg file?

Comment: From Neo4j 3.0 access to neo4j-shell is no longer possible from the desktop-installers for Windows and OSX.   Please Refer https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/using-neo4j-shell-neo4j-ce-3x/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I tried fixing it with the following:

Using a terminal, execute the following:

`$ curl -o "/Applications/Neo4j Community Edition.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/neo4j-shared.sh" http://fossies.org/linux/misc/neo4j-3.0.1.tar.gz/neo4j-3.0.1/packaging/standalone/src/main/distribution/shell-scripts/bin/neo4j-shared.sh?m=t`

That resolved the missing file but the DMG-packaged JAR seems to not have some Import and Shell classes. I ended up using the [Gzipped tarball](http://info.neo4j.com/download-thanks.html?edition=community&release=3.0.1&flavour=unix&_ga=1.125379074.948602705.1460868030) instead.

Comment: just be aware that version changes periodically - check a link in browser before.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known neo4j issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7566) that will be [will be fixed in version 3.1](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/7501).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Just download the tar.gz file from Neo4J's site and run the bin/neo4j-shell program that comes with it.

Answer (score -2):

The DMG comes with an visual installer.

Start the app "Neo4j Community Edition" which has a small starter-panel that also lives in the menu bar.

Comment: The app is working fine. I want to use neo4j-shell from command line, and that command isn't found.

Answer (score -3):

try to add ./ before your command. For example ./neo4j start or ./bin/neo4j start

Comment: I do not have Mac around me, but I think you need to be in neo4j home folder and then execute ./bin/neo4j start